Angular reactiveForms control - how to pass own input value as input parameter for a validator
I have created a control with code in my typescript file.
Now I want to use a custom check or validator.
How do I pass the input value as the parameter of the validator
this.formGroup.addControl('tunic', this.formBuilder.control('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(15), Validator.isValidIPv4String('HowToPassTheValueHere?') )]));

Here I am using a npm package directly in the validators. I also have written a method but that was overkill.
ALSO: Any tips to make the title better is apricated, so other devs can find it better when facing this issue.

Can you provide the implementation for Validator.isValidIPv4String?

https://ip-num.github.io/ip-num/classes/validator.validator.html#isvalidipv4string
This check needs a string as input

A validator is a function that received as parameter an AbstractControl and return null or an object.
You can use a function that return a validator
export class function isValidIPv4String(arg:any)
{
   return (control:AbstractControl)=>{
      ..you logic here
   }
}

But this only works if the "arg" is fixed. So you can use
control=new FormControl('',isValidIPv4String("some value"))

but
//the validator is with the value actual of the variable
//If you change the value of the variable the validator NOT change
//still use the old value of variable

control=new FormControl('',isValidIPv4String(this.variable))

If you want to use a variable you need "bind" the function
control=new FormControl('',isValidIPv4String().bind(this))

And inside the function you has access to the varibales of the component, see, e.g. this SO

@Eliseo explained that you need to implement a custom ValidatorFn as this Validator.isValidIPv4String method is not part of Reactive Form Validator function.
export function isValidIPv4String(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    let [isValid, _] = Validator.isValidIPv4String(control.value);

    if (!isValid) return { isValidIPv4: true };

    return null;
  };
}

Next, provide the isValidIPv4String validator into the validators list for tunic control.
this.formGroup.addControl(
  'tunic',
  this.formBuilder.control('', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.maxLength(15),
    isValidIPv4String()
  ])
);

Demo @ StackBlitz

thank you for your feedback. I have used my own valdation utilty for this. I upvoted your answer because it helped me a lot for finding the solution for my issue

I updated my validator utility (just a file which holds more custom validations)
import { AbstractControl, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';
import { Validator } from 'ip-num/Validator';
export abstract class ValidationUtility {

  static validateIPadres(version): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
      var ipadres: string = control.value;
      let result: [boolean, string[]] = null;

      result =  version === 4 ? Validator.isValidIPv4String(ipadres) : version === 6 ? Validator.isValidIPv6String(ipadres) : null;

      return result[0] === true ? null : {'ipadres' : 'invalid ipadres'};
    }
  }
}

NOTE: I removed a check for version (4 or 6) because it will never be set dynamically in my code. it is always set hardcoded in my code. There was no need to add this. (someone else can add this when needed)
And in my ts file i have this line of code:
this.formGroup.addControl('your-control-id', this.formBuilder.control(this.DNSRecord?.content ? this.DNSRecord.content : '', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(15), ValidationUtility.validateIPadres(4)]));

